# How to grant MySQL privileges in a bash script?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, sql-grant

I need to grant privileges to a database from within a bash script. Some parameters are in the form of variables, say, the username and the password. The command in a mysql shell would look like this:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO "$user"@localhost IDENTIFIED BY "$password";
```

...Except that `$user` and `$password` would be replaced by their values.

Is there a way to perform such a command from within a bash script?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There you go :)

```
#!/bin/bash

MYSQL=`which mysql`
EXPECTED_ARGS=3

Q1="USE $1;"
Q2="GRANT ALL ON *.* TO '$1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$2';"
Q3="FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
SQL="${Q1}${Q2}${Q3}"

if [ $# -ne $EXPECTED_ARGS ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 dbname dbuser dbpass"
  exit $E_BADARGS
fi

$MYSQL -uroot -p -e "$SQL"
```

Comment: I am sorry but that's not an answer to my question.

Comment: @Dunaril why do you say that this is not an answer to your question? It looks, at first glance, that this would work.

Comment: @Dunaril I see. Mr. Jauzsika should get used to put **UPDATE** when he updates his answers.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without getting the prompt for password?

Comment: In `grant` statement, I think we are missing `privileges`. I've tested your suggestion but it doesn't work unless I add privileges.

Answer (score 0):

If we don´t know the password we can get it with:

```
cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow
```

So we can get into mysql without prompt password like:

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`
```